# What's an accurate easy-to-understand way of referring to the brown outer part of a fried egg?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

[image]

The outer brown part. What's a good/easy-to-understand to refer to it?

Comment: You just did: the crunchy, crispy outermost portion of a fried egg.

Comment: There's no word or set phrase for this. You just describe it as best you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [crispy](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+crispy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) part? (of food, typically cooked food) having a pleasingly firm, dry, and brittle surface or texture; pleasantly thin, dry, and easily broken, appealingly [**crunchy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crispy)

I would use the [**crisp**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisp?show=0&t=1392261052) of an egg. (having close stiff or wiry curls or waves)

Comment: crisp of an egg?? Never heard or seen that.

Answer (score 6):

Some common phrases are *crispy edges* and *burnt edges*, and they are easy to understand. These or similar phrases are used in "how to fry an egg" tutorials and egg recipes also.

Example usages:

> An egg, sunny-side up, cooked in butter or enough oil with no chewy whites or **burnt edges**. 
> <sub>[*sophisticatedgourmet.com*](https://www.sophisticatedgourmet.com/2020/04/how-to-fry-an-egg/)</sub>

> It's hard to beat the satisfaction of a perfectly fried egg with its delightfully **crispy edges** and bright, creamy yolk. 
> <sub>[*mashed.com*](https://www.mashed.com/768020/big-mistakes-everyone-makes-when-frying-eggs)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

'caramelized eggwhite' should do.

Comment: I would actually peg this as "not easy to understand" for two reasons: (1) *eggwhite* contains *white*, when the subject in question is brown; (2) *caramelized* refers to a specific process whose effects (browning) may not be known to the audience. In other words, it requires too much thought.

Comment: Nope. "Caramelization is an entirely different process from Maillard browning, though the results of the two processes are sometimes similar to the naked eye (and taste buds). Caramelization may sometimes cause browning in the same foods in which the Maillard reaction occurs, but the two processes are distinct. They are both promoted by heating, but the Maillard reaction involves amino acids, whereas caramelization is the pyrolysis of certain sugars."https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've always called it [frizz](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frizz) - based on the verb defined there as...

> *to form into **small, crisp curls** or little tufts.*

But I'm not very specific in my usage. That same word also does me for the little dribs of batter that fall off fried fish (when I'm not collectively calling them [frazzles](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frazzle?s=t) *- frayed ends or remnants*).

Answer (score 0):

My family always called it ***gristle***, which really refers to cartilage or the tough inedible part of the meat. But I think it fits. I hate when fried eggs have that crispy tough stuff on the bottom, the texture is not for me.

Comment: Hi Jen, this would benefit from a source or citation of the usage.   Please see the [help].  As it stands, it's not clear (plus some people don't eat these things, so more clarification would really help).  Do you mean fried eggs have cartilage like bone gristle ?

Comment: Your suggestion is a reasonable offering. Answers here, though, don't rate for their good intentions but for their substance, as in *This is **the answer*** much more than *Here may be an idea for you*.